# How to populate CreateView hidden field with Data from URL?

Tags: python, django, view, create-view

I have a generic CreateView to create a ModelInstance that has a ForeignKey to another Model. The user gets there by clicking a link on the other Models DetailView. Instead of the user choosing the ForeignKey Object I'd like to hide this field and prepopulate it from an ID passed in the URL similar to this:

```
url(r'^t/(?P<pk>\d+)/add_r/$', ReceiptCreateForTask.as_view(), name="receipt_create_for_task"),
```

Which function do I have to override to access the 'pk' in the url and pass it into the form data before validation so it counts as input to the hidden field?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `get` method of `ReceiptCreateForTask`, in which you can access the `pk` in the url with `self.kwargs['pk']`.